# Counting number in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark SQL and my task is to count number of airports by state. I have already prepared my code but after execution the below error appears. Could you please point what is wrong here?

```
result_number_of_airports = spark.sql(
  "SELECT state, COUNT(DISTINCT airport) AS number_of_airports \
  FROM airports \
  GROUP BY state \
  ORDER BY number_of_airports DESC")
```

Schema

```
airports:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
IATA_CODE:string
AIRPORT:string
CITY:string
STATE:string
COUNTRY:string
LATITUDE:string
LONGITUDE:string
```

Error message

```
AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`state`' given input columns: [airports.ActualElapsedTime, airports.AirTime, airports.AirlineID, airports.ArrDel15, airports.ArrDelay, airports.ArrDelayMinutes, airports.ArrTime, airports.ArrTimeBlk, airports.ArrivalDelayGroups, airports.CRSArrTime, airports.CRSDepTime, airports.CRSElapsedTime, airports.CancellationCode, airports.Cancelled, airports.Carrier, airports.CarrierDelay, airports.DayOfWeek, airports.DayofMonth, airports.DepDel15, airports.DepDelay, airports.DepDelayMinutes, airports.DepTime, airports.DepTimeBlk, airports.DepartureDelayGroups, airports.Dest, airports.DestAirportID, airports.DestAirportSeqID, airports.DestCityMarketID, airports.DestCityName, airports.DestState, airports.DestStateFips, airports.DestStateName, airports.DestWac, airports.Distance, airports.DistanceGroup, airports.Div1Airport, airports.Div1AirportID, airports.Div1AirportSeqID, airports.Div1LongestGTime, airports.Div1TailNum, airports.Div1TotalGTime, airports.Div1WheelsOff, airports.Div1WheelsOn, airports.Div2Airport, airports.Div2AirportID, airports.Div2AirportSeqID, airports.Div2LongestGTime, airports.Div2TailNum, airports.Div2TotalGTime, airports.Div2WheelsOff, airports.Div2WheelsOn, airports.Div3Airport, airports.Div3AirportID, airports.Div3AirportSeqID, airports.Div3LongestGTime, airports.Div3TailNum, airports.Div3TotalGTime, airports.Div3WheelsOff, airports.Div3WheelsOn, airports.Div4Airport, airports.Div4AirportID, airports.Div4AirportSeqID, airports.Div4LongestGTime, airports.Div4TailNum, airports.Div4TotalGTime, airports.Div4WheelsOff, airports.Div4WheelsOn, airports.Div5Airport, airports.Div5AirportID, airports.Div5AirportSeqID, airports.Div5LongestGTime, airports.Div5TailNum, airports.Div5TotalGTime, airports.Div5WheelsOff, airports.Div5WheelsOn, airports.DivActualElapsedTime, airports.DivAirportLandings, airports.DivArrDelay, airports.DivDistance, airports.DivReachedDest, airports.Diverted, airports.FirstDepTime, airports.FlightDate, airports.FlightNum, airports.Flights, airports.LateAircraftDelay, airports.LongestAddGTime, airports.Month, airports.NASDelay, airports.Origin, airports.OriginAirportID, airports.OriginAirportSeqID, airports.OriginCityMarketID, airports.OriginCityName, airports.OriginState, airports.OriginStateFips, airports.OriginStateName, airports.OriginWac, airports.Quarter, airports.SecurityDelay, airports.TailNum, airports.TaxiIn, airports.TaxiOut, airports.TotalAddGTime, airports.UniqueCarrier, airports.WeatherDelay, airports.WheelsOff, airports.WheelsOn, airports.Year, airports._c109]; line 1 pos 87;
```

Answer (score 0):

Temp table was not correctly assigned.

I have changed from

```
temp_table_name = "flights"
flights.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name)

temp_table_name = "airlines"
airlines.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name)

temp_table_name = "airports"
airports.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name)
```

to

```
temp_table_name1 = "flights"
flights.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name1)

temp_table_name2 = "airlines"
flights.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name2)

temp_table_name3 = "airports"
flights.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table_name3)
```